# merging mulitple list of lists in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

let's say I have multiple lists of lists, I'll a include a shortened version of  three of them in this example.

```
list1=[['name', '1A5ZA'], ['length', 83], ['A', 28], ['V', 31], ['I', 24]]
list2=[['name', '1AJ8A'], ['length', 49], ['A', 18], ['V', 11], ['I', 20]]
list3=[['name', '1AORA'], ['length', 96], ['A', 32], ['V', 49], ['I', 15]]
```

all of the lists are in the same format: they have the same number of nested lists, with the same labels.

I generate each of these lists with the following function

```
def GetResCount(sequence):  
    residues=[['A',0],['V',0],['I',0],['L',0],['M',0],['F',0],['Y',0],['W',0],
    ['S',0],['T',0],['N',0],['Q',0],['C',0],['U',0],['G',0],['P',0],['R',0],
    ['H',0],['K',0],['D',0],['E',0]]

    name=sequence[0:5]
    AAseq=sequence[27:]
    for AA in AAseq:
        for n in range(len(residues)):
            if residues[n][0] == AA:
                residues[n][1]=residues[n][1]+1
    length=len(AAseq)
    nameLsit=(['name', name])
    lengthList=(['length', length])
    residues.insert(0,lengthList)
    residues.insert(0,nameLsit)
    return residues
```

the script takes a sequence such as this

```
1A5ZA:A|PDBID|CHAIN|SQUENCEMKIGIVGLGRVGSSTAFAL
```

and will create a list similar to the ones mentioned above. 
As each individual list is generated, I would like to append it to a final form, such that all of them combined together looks like this:

```
final=[['name', '1A5ZA', '1AJ8A', '1AORA'], ['length', 83, 49, 96], ['A', 28, 18, 32], ['V', 31, 11, 49], ['I', 24, 20, 15]]
```

maybe the final form of the data isn't in the right format. I am open to suggestion on how to format the final form better...

To summarize, what the script should do is to get a sequence of letters with the name of the sequence being at beginning, count the occurrence of each letter withing the sequence as well as the overall sequence length, and output the name length and the letter frequency to a list. Then it should combine the info from each sequence into a larger list(maybe dictionary?..)

at the very end all of this info will go into a spreadsheet that will look like this:

```
name    length  A   V   I
1A5ZA     83    28  31  24
1AJ8A     49    18  11  20
1AORA     96    32  49  15
```

I'm including this last bit because maybe I'm not starting starting in the right way to end up with what I want.

Anyway, 
I hope you made it here and thanks for the help!

Comment: Your `final` format is expressive and you can loop through `zip(*final)` then you can print the results or write them in a text file, csv, etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you are looking for a table then a `dict` might be a better approach. (Note: `collections.Counter` does the same as your counting), e.g.:

```py
from collections import Counter

def GetResCount(sequence):
    name, AAseq = sequence[0:5], sequence[27:]
    residuals = {'name': name, 'length': len(AAseq), 'A': 0, 'V': 0, 'I': 0, 'L': 0,
                 'M': 0, 'F': 0, 'Y': 0, 'W': 0, 'S': 0, 'T': 0, 'N': 0, 'Q': 0, 'C': 0,
                 'U': 0, 'G': 0, 'P': 0, 'R': 0, 'H': 0, 'K': 0, 'D': 0, 'E': 0}
    residuals.update(Counter(AAseq))
    return residuals

In []:
GetResCount('1A5ZA:A|PDBID|CHAIN|SQUENCEMKIGIVGLGRVGSSTAFAL')

Out[]:
{'name': '1A5ZA', 'length': 19, 'A': 2, 'V': 2, 'I': 2, 'L': 2, 'M': 1, 'F': 1, 'Y': 0,
 'W': 0, 'S': 2, 'T': 1, 'N': 0, 'Q': 0, 'C': 0, 'U': 0, 'G': 4, 'P': 0, 'R': 1,
 'H': 0, 'K': 1, 'D': 0, 'E': 0}
```

Note: this may only be in the order you might be looking in Py3.6+ but we can fix that later as we create the table if necessary.

Then you can create a list of the dicts, e.g. (assuming you are reading these lines from a file):

```
with open(<file>) as file:
    data = [GetResCount(line.strip()) for line in file]
```

Then you can load it directly into `pandas`, e.g.:

```
In []:
import pandas as pd
columns = ['name', 'length', 'A', 'V', 'I', ...]  # columns = list(data[0].keys()) - Py3.6+
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
print(df)

Out[]:
    name  length  A  V  I ...
0  1A5ZA      83 28 31 24 ...
1  1AJ8A      49 18 11 20 ...
2  1AORA      96 32 49 15 ...
...
```

You could also just dump it out to a file with `cvs.DictWriter()`:

```
from csv import DictWriter

fieldnames = ['name', 'length', 'A', 'V', 'I', ...]
with open(<output>, 'w') as file:
    writer = DictWrite(file, fieldnames)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Which would output something like:

```
name,length,A,V,I,...
1A5ZA,83,28,31,24,...
1AJ8A,49,18,11,20,...
1AORA,96,32,49,15 ...
...
```